# How do I hide all windows in Ubuntu 18.04 by one click?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, show-desktop

Just updated my Ubuntu to 18.04, but I couldn't find how to hide all windows with one click by the icon. In 16.04 it was something like "show Desktop" icon on the Ubuntu dock (left sidebar).

Answer (score 3):

Change this setting:

> Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Navigation -> Hide all normal windows

This is the setting you need.

Comment: Thank you but I needed the icon in the sidebar (similar like in windows).

Answer (score 3):

Just press Super (the "Windows" key) + D to immediately hide all of the open windows, and the same again to bring them back...

Comment: Super+D seems to be disabled by default in Ubuntu 18.04.  I had to change this in the settings (as explained in the answer by mk1024).

Comment: How strange - it was ENABLED by default for me (and no this wasn't an upgrade - I "clean" install new Ubuntu LTS versions)!

Comment: I think mine was an upgrade, perhaps that explains it.